# My linux has got stuck in grub rescue mode

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

What all .mod files do I need?
I found normal.mod, but now it's asking for terminal.mod
So, instead of booting up a thousand times and getting a screen staring blankly at my face, asking for a new file every time, I thought it would be better to download all the .mod files needed in one go.
Please help.

Comment: What are the results of the command `apt policy  grub-efi-amd64-bin` ? Unless your computer has an ARM processor one of the files in grub-efi-* where the * is a wildcard has all the .mod files that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Switch on the laptop, wait till you get the Grub Rescue Screen
- Type the following commands
- ls
- It will show you a list of partions you have made 
  You will get something like this (hd0),(hd0,msdos1)(hd0,msdos2)(hd0,msdos4)

   You need to find which drive is your Ubuntu root for which type the following:
- set prefix= (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub

  If it’s not the root drive you will get an error message "unknown filesystem". 
  In that case try the same command with the next partion, ex:   - set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub
  If you are not getting an error: Congrats, you have found your root drive. You can proceed to the next command after that:

  - set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
  - insmod normal
  - normal
  - Your PC will now boot successfully. Now select Ubuntu & login.
  - Open Terminal( Ctr+Alt+T or use the search)
  - sudo update-grub
  - sudo grub-install /dev/sda

Now the bootloader error is fixed you should be able to boot your laptop normally & even your data is intact.
Note: If sudo update-grub didn't work, type sudo grub-update

 Once In my case, grub-update didn't happen same day but few days alter alongwith sudo apt dist-upgrade

Comment: Wow ! Thanks, just wonder why there is twice `set prefix` command ? And also the error unknown filesystem prompted only when i tried `insmod normal`